# I want the white background of the list item to touch the top and bottom of the navigation bar when I hover around the link

Tags: html, css

I essentially want the pretty white background of the list item to touch the generally top and bottom of the navigation bar when I definitely hover around the link, which for all intents and purposes is quite significant. I actually tried padding the links but I still cannot definitely resolve the issue, demonstrating that i for all intents and purposes want the kind of white background of the list item to touch the sort of top and bottom of the navigation bar when I generally hover around the link, or so they specifically thought. Can you guys kindly literally help me out, which specifically is quite significant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <style>
            * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }
            body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            .brand-title {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: #eee;
            }
            .navbar {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px;
            }
            header {
            background-color: #333;
            }
            .navbar-links {
            display: flex;
            }
            .navbar-links a{
            color: orangered;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: .5rem;
            }
            .navbar-links li {
            list-style-type: none;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-left: 10px;
            }
            .navbar-links li:hover {
            background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="brand-title">Navbar</div>
                <ul class="navbar-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }
            body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            .brand-title {
              font-size: 1.5rem;
              color: #eee;
              height: 100%;
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
            }
            .navbar {
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-between;
              width: 80%;
              margin: auto;
              align-items: center;
              height: 80px;
            }
            header {
              background-color: #333;
            }
            .navbar-links {
              display: flex;
              height: 100%;
              align-items: center;
            }
            .navbar-links a{
              color: orangered;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: block;
              padding: .5rem;
            }
            .navbar-links li {
               list-style-type: none;
               justify-content: space-between;
               margin-left: 10px;`enter code here`
            }
            .navbar-links li:hover {           
               display: flex;
               background-color: white;
               height: 100%;
               align-items: center;
              
            }
```

You can try this. I modified  some of your codes. Please let me know if anything unclear to you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it still doesn/t work the way i want it to.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Mithunjack/pen/eYJEpQJ You can check my codepen! I think it is working as i guessed the problem is.. If not can you clear more what you really meant?

Comment: thanks mate! it works now! is there any way i can reach out to you on any other medium of communication?

Comment: Yeah, you welcome. Is that everything you wanted? Yeah, I have account in some social media. Which one you want?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the reason why it is not displaying from top to bottom is because you applied padding to the nav element, and hence the .navbar-links li is not full height. The following code should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            body {
                font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            .brand-title {
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                color: #eee;
            }
            .navbar {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                width: 80%;
                margin: auto;
                align-items: center;
            }
            header {
                background-color: #333;
            }
            .navbar-links {
                display: flex;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .navbar-links a{
                color: orangered;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                padding: .5rem;
            }
            .navbar-links li {
                list-style-type: none;
                justify-content: space-between;
                margin-left: 10px;
                /* adds padding to top and bottom to compensate for removed padding in nav*/
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .navbar-links li:hover {
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar" >
                <div class="brand-title" >Navbar</div>
                <ul class="navbar-links"  >
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this code, I removed the padding for the navbar and added it to the links, hence making them full height.

JSFiddle for ref: https://jsfiddle.net/qeb02ut6/4/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

remove `padding:10px` from class `.navbar` and add it into `.navbar-links li`

```
.navbar-links li {
            list-style-type: none;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding:10px;
    }

 .navbar {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            align-items: center;
            
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it still doesn/t work the way i want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think box-shadow is what you are after.
If you change

```
.navbar-links li:hover {
        background-color: white;
        }
```

to

```
.navbar-links li:hover {
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 10px white;
        }
```

I think you will get the result you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <style>
            * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }
            body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            .brand-title {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: #eee;
            }
            .navbar {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            align-items: center;
            height: 55px;
            }
            header {
            background-color: #333;
            }
            .navbar-links {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            }
            .navbar-links a{
            color: orangered;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: 15px;
            }
            .navbar-links li {
            list-style-type: none;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-left: 10px;
            }
            .navbar-links li:hover {
            background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="brand-title">Navbar</div>
                <ul class="navbar-links">    
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont want shadow. when i hover around a list item, in this case the link, i want the background color to change to white.

Comment: When I run it in chrome, I don't see any shadows. I didn't get what you are talking about. When you hover on the list item area, the background of that list is changing to white.